# LARAVEL Font and style changed after login

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a problem while styling my Laravel. I've downloaded a third party theme and css file one for the user template and the other one is for the admin panel template. Both have different css styling. The problem occurred when the user tried to log in and the font, title logo, and some button color in the user hompage suddenly changed. I've stored the files separately, I created admin folder for the admin, and for the user I just paste it in the public folder.

Here is my code for both user and admin.

```
---ADMIN Home.blade.php---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    @include('admin.css')
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
      <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
      @include('admin.sidebar')
      <!-- partial -->
      @include('admin.navbar')
        <!-- partial -->
    <!-- container-scroller -->
    <!-- plugins:js -->
    @include('admin.script')
    <!-- End custom js for this page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
---ADMIN css.blade.php---
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <!-- plugins:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Plugin css for this page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/owl-carousel-2/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/vendors/owl-carousel-2/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <!-- End plugin css for this page -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Layout styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- End layout styles -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="admin/assets/images/favicon.png" />
```

```
---USER Home.blade.php---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>E-Konsultasi</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/maicons.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor/animate/animate.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/theme.css">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Back to top button -->
  <div class="back-to-top"></div>

  <header>
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 text-sm">
            <div class="site-info">
              <a href="#"><span class="mai-call text-primary"></span> </a>
              <span class="divider">|</span>
              <a href="#"><span class="mai-mail text-primary"></span> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-right text-sm">
            <div class="social-mini-button">
              <a href=""><span class="mai-logo-youtube"></span></a>
              <a href=""><span class="mai-logo-instagram"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- .row -->
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </div> <!-- .topbar -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light shadow-sm">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="text-primary">E</span>-Konsultasi</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupport">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Beranda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#layanan">Layanan</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Kontak</a>
            </li>

            @if (Route::has('login'))
            
            @auth

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('cek_konsul')}}">Cek Status Konsul</a>
            </li>

            <x-app-layout>

            </x-app-layout>            

            @else

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="btn btn-primary ml-lg-3" href="{{route('register')}}">Login / Register</a>
            </li>

            @endauth

            @endif

          </ul>
        </div> <!-- .navbar-collapse -->
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </nav>
  </header>

  @if (session()->has('message'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
           {{session()->get('message')}}
   </div>
  @endif

  <div class="page-hero bg-image overlay-dark" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/Consult01.jpg);">
    <div class="hero-section">
      <div class="container text-center wow zoomIn">
        <span class="subhead">Konsultasi Seputar</span>
        <h1 class="display-4">Barang dan Jasa</h1>
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            
            @auth
            @else

              <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Konsultasi Sekarang</a>

            @endauth

            @endif
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bg-light">
    <div class="page-section py-3 mt-md-n5 custom-index">
      <div class="container">
        
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .page-section -->

    <div class="page-section pb-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-lg-6 py-3 wow fadeInUp">
            <h1>Konsultasi Masalah<br> Berbasis Elektronik</h1>
            <p class="text-grey mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Accusantium aperiam earum ipsa eius, inventore nemo labore eaque porro consequatur ex aspernatur. Explicabo, excepturi accusantium! Placeat voluptates esse ut optio facilis!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="400ms">
            <div class="img-place custom-img-1">
              <img src="../assets/img/logoukpbj.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .bg-light -->
  </div> <!-- .bg-light -->

  <div class="page-section" id="layanan">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-5 wow fadeInUp">Jenis Layanan</h1>

      <div class="owl-carousel wow fadeInUp" id="doctorSlideshow">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="card-doctor">
            <div class="header">
              <img height="300px" src="../assets/img/isiform.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <p class="text-xl mb-0">Isi Form<br> Konsultasi</p>
              <span class="text-sm text-grey">Lengakapi formulir dan submit keluhan dan permasalahan yang ingin ditanyakan.</span>
            
              @if (Route::has('login'))
            
                @auth
                 <div class="col text-center">
                  <a href="{{url('form_konsul')}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
                 </div>
                @else
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
                </div>
                @endauth

              @endif
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="card-doctor">
            <div class="header">
              <img height="300px" src="../assets/img/f2f01.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <p class="text-xl mb-0">Buat Jadwal Konsul Tatap Muka</p>
              <span class="text-sm text-grey">Atur jadwal konsul tatap muka bersama admin secara langsung.</span>
              
              @if (Route::has('login'))
            
              @auth
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
                </div>
              @else
              <div class="col text-center">
                <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
              </div>
              @endauth

            @endif
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="card-doctor">
            <div class="header">
              <img height="300px" src="../assets/img/zoom01.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <p class="text-xl mb-0">Buat Jadwal Konsul Online</p>
              <span class="text-sm text-grey">Atur jadwal konsul secara online melalui aplikasi zoom meeting.</span>
            
                            
              @if (Route::has('login'))
            
              @auth
              <div class="col text-center">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
              </div>
              @else
              <div class="col text-center">
                <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Isi Sekarang</a>
              </div>
              @endauth

            @endif

              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row px-md-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 py-3">
          <h5>E-Konsultasi</h5>
          <p class="footer-link mt-2">Unit Kerja Pengadaan Barang dan Jasa Sekretariat Daerah Kota Pontianak</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 py-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 py-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 py-3">
          <h5>Kontak</h5>
          <p class="footer-link mt-2"></p>
          <a href="#" class="footer-link"></a>
          <a href="#" class="footer-link"></a>

          <h5 class="mt-3">Social Media</h5>
          <div class="footer-sosmed mt-3">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="mai-logo-youtube"></span></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="mai-logo-instagram"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2022 E-Konsultasi UKPBJ. All right reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

<script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/vendor/owl-carousel/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/vendor/wow/wow.min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/theme.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I did wrong? Thank

Comment: You should use extends, section  / yield, include, stack / push  etc.. , do not put all your html in one blade view, if your view is more that 100 lines there is an issue, you should separate each section, the footer should have his own view, like the header etc...

Comment: @Lk77 Thanks for the comment, I will be doing that for the user part. Also do you know why my css style kinda overlap with some of the admin css?

Comment: You should use the asset() helper, i think your src is wrong ( the ../ part )